# django template: get data from dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I'm new to django and Im tring to get data out of dictionary

variable **number_of_books** has dictionary as shown below

```
[{'num_books': 3, 'name': u'comp science'}, {'num_books': 1, 'name': u'electronics'}, {'num_books': 0, 'name': u'civil'}]
```

In my django template I tried to get data, but could not succeed

```
{% for key, value in number_of_books.items %}
    <li>{{key}} - {{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

please help in getting data in my template

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than just giving you the answer, I think it would be more beneficial for the community to help you troubleshoot.

Your django server is running, correct? What error message is it throwing?

Comment: Im not able to see anything in templates........there is no error also

Comment: Ok, so if your server isn't throwing any error messages and you're comfortable with the code in the view, we can rule that out. So then, does console show any errors when you load the page in browser? If you inspect the HTML source, what does it look like?

Comment: no console errors also........I made mistake in looping....Shang Wang helped me (answer below).........thanks disflux

Comment: Ok. But somebody just giving you the answer isn't going to help you better your debugging skills. If you are entering the world of Django and you are new to Python, the best advice anybody can give you is to enforce learning debugging methods and find debugging tools. Something like this would have been a couple minute debug and fix rather than requiring a post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a list of dicts not a dict, so looping like that wouldn't work. You should do:

```
{% for item in number_of_books %}
    <li>{{ item.num_books }} - {{ item.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I DO hope you understand the difference of looping a dict vs. looping a list. Please let me know if you need help on that.